# How to show a circle over video in tkinter?

Tags: javascript, python

I wanted to know if there is a way in **Tkinter** to simply play a video and with a button press, a circle appears on top of the video?.

Comment: Show us your code for playing the video. If you are doing it with opencv for example, it is very easy.

Comment: first problem can be displaying video :) if you use `opencv` then you have to read frame by frame and you get image on which you can draw anything, or you can put image on canvas and draw circle also on canvas, and later you can replace image without drawing circle.

Comment: example code which displays video from built-in webcam using OpenCV (but OpenCV can also work with files or urls). In code in comments there are functions which add text or rectangle to image. [github / furas / python-examples / cv2 / tkinter-CV - minimal version](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/cv2/tkinter-CV%20-%20minimal%20version/main.py)

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `OpenCV` (`cv2`) to read video (from file, URL or webcam) then you get frame-by-frame and you can draw figures or text using `cv2` or `Pillow`

---

This code gets frames from webcam using `cv2` and it adds

- red text and red rectangle using `cv2`
- green text and green rectangle using `Pillow`
- blue text and blue rectangle using `tkinter`

`tkinter` has to add text and rectangle only once because they are separated objects (not part of image). Other modules have to draw on image.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk , ImageDraw, ImageFont
import cv2

# --- functions ---

def update_frame():

    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if ret:
        # convert color from BGR to RGB (because `CV2` uses `BGR`)
        frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
            
        # red - draw using CV2 (before converting to PIL)
        frame = cv2.rectangle(frame, (280,150,80,80), color=(255,0,0), thickness=2)
        frame = cv2.putText(frame, "Hello World!", (10, 60), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255,0,0)) 

        # convert to PIL
        image = Image.fromarray(frame)
        
        # green - draw using PIL (after converting from CV2)
        image_draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
        font = ImageFont.truetype('Pillow/Tests/fonts/FreeMono.ttf', 40)
        image_draw.text((10,60), "Hello World!", font=font, fill=(0,255,0))
        image_draw.rectangle((280,250,360,330), outline=(0,255,0), width=3)
        
        # copy image from PIL.Image to tkinter.PhotoImage
        photo.paste(image) 

    root.after(40, update_frame) # update again after 40ms - it should give 25 FPS (1000ms/40ms = 25)

# --- main ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture('movie.mp4)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture("https://imageserver.webcamera.pl/rec/krakow4/latest.mp4")

# get first frame to create photo
ret, frame = cap.read()

# - GUI -

root = tk.Tk()

# create first image
image = Image.fromarray(frame)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)  # it has to be after `tk.Tk()`

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=photo.width(), height=photo.height())
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)

# add image to canvas
image_id = canvas.create_image((0,0), image=photo, anchor='nw')

# blue - draw using tkinter (it needs to draw only once)
rect_id = canvas.create_rectangle(380, 150, 460, 230, outline='blue', width=3)
text_id = canvas.create_text(10, 100, text="Hello World!", fill='blue', font=('Arial', 30), anchor='nw')

# - start -

update_frame() # update it first time

root.mainloop()  # run loop all time - it shows window

# - after close window -

# close stream
cap.release()
```

Result:

It is in dark room so you can see only my face.

[image]

---

**EDIT:**

Project [python-cv2-streams-viewer](https://github.com/furas/python-cv2-streams-viewer) shows more complex example which displays video with many streams at the same time.